# content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, illegalstateexception

I got the following error:

> Java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.

I am calling from `onPostExecute` method, I am after set adapter and I am doing `setNotifyDataChanged` but still not working. Why?

```
if(forumqbfilter_list.size() > 0 && forumqbfilter_list != null) { 
    forumAdapter = new ForumAdapter(ForumViewActivity.this); 
    LV_forums.setAdapter(forumAdapter); forumAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
} else { 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Forums Available", 20).show(); 
}
```

Comment: You should called `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after adapter data updates from main `UiThread`.

Comment: i am already calling but still not working

Comment: why? post your code i want to see. how you called?

Comment: What is this? edit your question and post your all code in your question.

Comment: if(forumqbfilter_list.size() > 0 && forumqbfilter_list != null) {
   forumAdapter = new ForumAdapter(ForumViewActivity.this);
   LV_forums.setAdapter(forumAdapter);
                forumAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   
 
   
   } else {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Forums Available", 20).show();
  }

Answer (score -1):

Call `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()` to update your list view.

Comment: forumAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); i  am adding but still not working